# What is the need for a constructor() in es6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What role does constructor() play in es6 Javascript while creating component classes?  I'm kinda new to this and hopped on this while trying to learn React.

Comment: Just usual role constructors play in all classes.

Comment: Why don't you just read a tutorial or documentation?

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-constructor

Comment: MDN is always helpful to get started , try this url for constructors: 
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 1):

Response above is in part right:

```
Constructor called when your object is created.
```

But in React stack, beacause *React classes are subclasses*, we have others caveheats:

1. Always call super() if you have a constructor and don't worry about it if you don't have a constructor
2. Call super(props) only if you want to access this.props inside the constructor. React automatically set it for you if you want to access it anywhere else.
3. There is no need to pass props into the constructor if you want to use it in other places. Because React automatically set it for you

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is called when your object is created.
You should try this code. It will output arguments into console.

```
class MyObject {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) {
        console.log(arg1, arg2);
        // output arguments
    }
}

var myobj = new MyObject("test1", "test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJs context: Constructor is the first lifecycle method which is called for the react component. It can be used for initializing the state.

```
class SomeComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prop1: "value"
    }
  }
}
```

But, now with newer version of javascript you can directly initialize the state. So actually there is no need to use constructor in components.

```
class SomeComp extends Component {
  state = {
    prop1: "value1"
  };
}
```